# A user can't read file but belong to the group

Tags: unix, permissions

I have a strange issue on my debian vm.

I have a nginx directory like that.

```
$ ll
total 9076
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       330645 juil. 13 10:40 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root      143902 juil. 12 01:08 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       852976 juil. 13 10:41 error.log
```

I try to read the access.log with the **foo** user.
So, I have added this user to adm group.

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep adm
adm:x:4:admin,foo
```

But the user can't read the file. I have tried to add the user to www-data group, but the problem is the same. Do you know what is the problem ?
I thought know how user/group works, it seems not :)

BR,

Eric

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To read a file, the user needs execute privileges to all of the parent directories.  If your logs are in `/var/log/nginx` make sure the `foo` user or one of its groups has `x` access to each directory (`/var`, `/var/log/`, `/var/log/nginx`) of whatever path logs are in.

Comment: HOLY COW!!! This question/answer is SO FUNDAMENTAL yet has _so few_ votes. Took forever to find this.